# Number of Increasing Subsequences of length k

Tags: c++, algorithm, lis, fenwick-tree

I am trying to understand the algorithm that gives me the number of increasing subsequences of length K in an array in time O(n*k*log(n)). I know how to solve this very same problem using the O(k*n^2) algorithm. I have looked up and found out this solution uses BIT (Fenwick Tree) and DP. I have also found some code, but I have not been able to understand it.

Here are some links I've visited that have been helpful.

[Here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862077/number-of-increasing-strings-of-length-k)

[Topcoder forum](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=617827&start=0&mc=14#996142)

[Random webpage](http://comovamos.factorcomun.org/problems/543-increasing-subsequences)

I would really appreciate if some can help me out understand this algorithm.

Comment: mind showing the code you found that has O(n*k*log(n)) complexity?

Comment: The topcoder link is now fixed. You can find it there.

Comment: It is easier to think about this without trying to do it with BIT straight away. I explain how here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057591/how-to-find-the-total-number-of-increasing-sub-sequences-of-certain-length-with/15058391#15058391

Comment: I cannot understand your algorithm. Could you please expand your explanation here in my post, and maybe give me an idea of that using Segment Trees, I will then come up with a solution using BIT.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have added some more explanations. Let me know exactly what isn't clear if you still have trouble understanding it and I will do my best to help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am reproducing my algorithm from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057591/how-to-find-the-total-number-of-increasing-sub-sequences-of-certain-length-with/15058391#15058391), where its logic is explained:

```
dp[i, j] = same as before num[i] = how many subsequences that end with i (element, not index this time) 
         have a certain length

for i = 1 to n do   dp[i, 1] = 1

for p = 2 to k do // for each length this time   num = {0}

  for i = 2 to n do
    // note: dp[1, p > 1] = 0 

    // how many that end with the previous element
    // have length p - 1
    num[ array[i - 1] ] += dp[i - 1, p - 1] *1*   

    // append the current element to all those smaller than it
    // that end an increasing subsequence of length p - 1,
    // creating an increasing subsequence of length p
    for j = 1 to array[i] - 1 do *2*       
      dp[i, p] += num[j]
```

You can optimize `*1*` and `*2*` by using segment trees or binary indexed trees. These will be used to efficiently process the following operations on the `num` array:

- Given `(x, v)` add `v` to `num[x]` (relevant for `*1*`);
- Given `x`, find the sum `num[1] + num[2] + ... + num[x]` (relevant for `*2*`).

These are trivial problems for both data structures.

**Note:** This will have complexity `O(n*k*log S)`, where `S` is the upper bound on the values in your array. This may or may not be good enough. To make it `O(n*k*log n)`, you need to normalize the values of your array prior to running the above algorithm. Normalization means converting all of your array values into values lower than or equal to `n`. So this:

```
5235 223 1000 40 40
```

Becomes:

```
4 2 3 1 1
```

This can be accomplished with a sort (keep the original indexes).

Comment: There is something I have not been able to understand. How does this algorithm guarantees that you are storing the number of INCREASING Subsquences. I know how the DP O(n*n*k) does, but this one... Not a clue

Comment: @Andrés - basically, you count how many of a certain length you have for each **value** (not index like in the classic DP). You can append the current value to all smaller values, obtaining +1 length.