# Concentric spheres

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, math, sequence, dynamic-programming

Two different lists having radii of upper hemisphere and lower hemisphere is provided. The first list consists of **N** upper hemispheres indexed 1 to **N** and the second has **M** lower hemispheres indexed 1 to **M**. A sphere of radius of **R** can be made taking one upper half of the radius **R** and one lower half of the radius **R**. Also, you can put a sphere into a bigger one and create a sequence of nested concentric spheres. But you can't put two or more spheres directly into another one.

If there is a sequence of (**D+1**) nested spheres, we can call this sequence as a **D**-sequence.

Find out how many different **X**-sequence are possible (**1** <= **X** <= **C**). An **X** sequence is different from another if the index of any of the hemisphere used in one **X**-sequence is different from the other.

**INPUT**

The first line contains a three integers: **N** denoting the number of upper sphere halves, **M** denoting the number of lower sphere halves and **C**.

The second line contains **N** space-separated integers  denoting the radii of upper hemispheres.

The third line contains **M** space-separated integers denoting the radii of lower hemispheres.

**OUTPUT**

Output a single line containing **C** space-separated integers , the number of ways there are to build **i**-sequence in modulo **1000000007**.

**Example**

**Input**

3 4 3

1 2 3

1 1 3 2

**Output**

5 2 0

I am looking for those elements which are part of both the lists of upper as well as lower hemispheres, so that they can form a sphere and then taking their maximum count by comparing their counts in both radii lists.

And, So, for different **C** sum of products of counts of **C+1** elements yields the answer.

How to calculate the above efficiently or is there any other approach ??

Comment: "appears to be a wrong approach" why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Guys this is my first answer. Spare me the whip for now as i am here to learn.

---

You first find the numbers of spheres possible for each radii.

```
no of spheres: 2 1 1
Having Radii:  1 2 3
```

Now since we can fit a sphere with radius r inside a sphere with radii R such that R>r, all we need to do is to find the no . of increasing subsequences of length 2,3,...till c in the list of all possible spheres formed.

```
List of possible spheres:[1,1*,2,3](* used for marking)
```

consider D1: it has 2 spheres. Try finding the no. of increasing subsequences of length 2 in the above list.
They are:

```
[1,2],[1*,2][1,3][1*,3][2,3]
```

hence the ans is 5.
Get it??
Now how to solve:
It can be done by using Dp. Naive solution has complexity .O(n^2*constant).
**You may follow along the lines as provided in the following link** :[Dp solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402854/number-of-increasing-subsequences-of-length-k).
It is worth mentioning that faster methods do exist which use BIT , segment trees etc.

---

It is similar to this [SPOJ problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/INCSEQ/).