# Number of restricted arrangements

Tags: algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

I am looking for a faster way to solve this problem:

Let's suppose we have **n boxes** and **n marbles** (each of them has a different kind). **Every box can contain only some kinds of marbles** (It is shown it the example below), and only one **marble fits inside one box**. **Please read the edits.** The whole algorithm has been described in the post linked below but it was not precisely described, so I am asking for a reexplenation.

### **The question is:** In how many ways can I put marbles inside the boxes in polynomial time?

Example:

```
n=3

Marbles: 2,5,3

Restrictions of the i-th box (i-th box can only contain those marbles): {5,2},{3,5,2},{3,2}

The answer: 3, because the possible positions of the marbles are: {5,2,3},{5,3,2},{2,5,3}
```

I have a solution which works in O(2^n), but it is too slow. There are also one limitation about the boxes tolerance, which I don't find very important, but I will write them also. Each box has it's own kind-restrictions, but there is one list of kinds which is accepted by all of them (in the example above this widely accepted kind is 2).

**Edit:** I have just found this question but I am not sure if it works in my case, and the dynamic solution is not well described. Could somebody clarify this? This question was answered 4 years ago, so I won't ask it there. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145985/how-to-compute-number-of-combinations-with-placement-restrictions?rq=1

**Edit#2:** I also have to mention that excluding widely-accepted list the maximum size of the acceptance list of a box has 0 1 or 2 elements.

**Edit#3:** This question refers to my previos question([Allowed permutations of numbers 1 to N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69740876/allowed-permutations-of-numbers-1-to-n)), which I found too general. I am attaching this link because there is also one more important information - the distance between boxes in which a marble can be put isn't higher than 2.

Comment: Some things are not clear to me. The condition "*only one marble fits inside one box*" how is honoured if in your example marbel "5" can fit in boxes 1 and 2? If box 3 only allows marbels 3 and 2 does its order matters?

Comment: @Ripi2 this condition just says that you can't put 2 marbles in one box. These box restricions just say which of the marbles you can put on this place. I don't understand the second part of your question. What order do you mean?

Comment: Putting each of n different marbels in each of n boxes has `n!` solutions. The restrictions will low this number, say to `(n-k)!` for some `k`. But its complexity is still factorial and not polynomial.

Comment: @Ripi2 Yes so the problem is to find this k, because I just need the number, not all the combinations. I have also found out an expression which let's me solve this, but it sometimes skips some cases

Comment: I think I should also mention it

Comment: Basically the SE post shows how to do it. First cakculate all posibilities. Then substract those cases that don't satisfy a box condition. Be careful not to count same "not-valid-case" more than once. While you can do it with pencil and paper, you can do dynamic programming, building a tree of options and trimming those wrong branches.

Comment: I have messed up because there is also one more thing I should have mentioned

Comment: @Ripi2 I need a minute to process it. What would be the complexity of your solution and what post are you talking about? I also have to mention that excluding widely-accepted list the maximum size of the acceptance list of a box has 0 1 or 2 elements.

Comment: The code you posted seems a hand-made solution. You calculate factorials using for-loops. I won't check that solution, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238729/discussion-between-chate-and-ripi2).

Comment: In response to this: *"which I don't find very important"*. The widely-accepted list makes the problem slightly easier. In your 2,5,3 example, the fact that 2 is widely accepted means that you can ignore the 2 while counting the arrangements. So the problem simplifies to counting the number of ways to put marbles 5,3 into boxes {5},{3,5},{3}. As a result, the problem in this question is exactly the same as the one in the math.stackexchange question (in that question there are more boxes than marbles).

Comment: @user3386109 I am sorry, my mistake. I just don't understand where is the dynamic programming in the post from the math.stackexchange. It is described there very quickly, and I don't undersnad it. I think that asking there is pointless due to date of this question. It would be very helpful if somebody reexplained this idea.

Comment: I reviewed the answer, and I agree with you that it glossed over the details of the dynamic programming solution, to the point where I don't know what the intended solution is. However, you can and should put a comment under that answer. The author (tbilly) is active here on stack overflow, and was last seen 3 days ago. So if you put a link to this question in your comment, there's a good chance you'll get an answer in a few days.

Comment: @user3386109 I have just created an account there and it seems that I must have at least 50 reputation to reply, so I can't really contact him.

Comment: The linked thread is hard to piece together. However, given the information in your 2nd edit, I believe this can be solved in polynomial time with the [FKT algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKT_algorithm). If you choose the 'all accepted' marble and some box B, and remove them from the graph, the remaining graph doesn't contain K_3,3 as a subgraph, so the FKT algorithm should work on it to count perfect matchings, repeating this process for each choice of initial box B.

Comment: @kcsquared and what would be the complexity of finding the number of the perfect matchings? The answer might be really big ~10^18

Comment: @kcsquared I don't really understand what do you do with the 'all accepted' marbles. Could you specify it/ eventually show it on a example?

Comment: I may have misunderstood what was meant by 'one list of kinds which is accepted by all of them'. If this means that there is at most one marble accepted in all boxes, the method I proposed works, since we can count perfect matchings in planar bipartite graphs efficiently. If there can be more than a constant number of marbles accepted in all boxes, the method breaks down, since counting maximum matchings in planar bipartite graphs is #P-complete. In either case, the algorithm is hard to find existing implementations of, so you may be better off with existing exponential solutions.

Comment: @kcsquared there can be a lot of them :(

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19924/counting-and-finding-all-perfect-maximum-matchings-in-general-graphs is this problem, with links to papers on how to tackle it, and counting the number of matchings is #P-complete.  I would recommend finding those papers.

As for dynamic programming, simply write a recursive solution and then memoize it.  (That's top down, and is almost always the easier approach.) For the stack exchange problem with a fixed (and fairly small) number of boxes, that approach is manageable.  Unfortunately in your variation with a large number of boxes, the naive recursive version looks something like this (untested, probably buggy):

```
def solve (balls, box_rules):
    ball_can_go_in = {}
    for ball in balls:
        ball_can_go_in[ball] = set()
    for i in range(len(box_rules)):
        for ball in box_rules[i]:
            ball_can_go_in[ball].add(i)

    def recursive_attempt (n, used_boxes):
        if n = len(balls):
            return 1
        else:
            answer = 0
            for box in ball_can_go_in[balls[n]]:
                if box not in used_boxes:
                    used_boxes.add(box)
                    answer += recursive_attempt(n+1, used_boxes)
                    used_boxes.remove(box)
             return answer

    return recursive_attempt(0, set())
```

In order to memoize it you have to construct new sets, maybe use bit strings, BUT you're going to find that you're calling it with subsets of n things.  There are an exponential number of them.  Unfortunately this will take exponential time AND use exponential memory.

If you replace the memoizing layer with an LRU cache, you can control how much memory it uses and probably still get some win from the memoizing.  But ultimately you will still use exponential or worse time.

If you go that route, one practical tip is sort the balls by how many boxes they go in.  You want to start with the fewest possible choices. Since this is trying to reduce exponential complexity, it is worth quite a bit of work on this sorting step.  So I'd first pick the ball that goes in the fewest boxes.  Then I'd next pick the ball that goes in the fewest new boxes, and break ties by fewest overall.  The third ball will be fewest new boxes, break ties by fewest boxes not used by the first, break ties by fewest boxes.  And so on.

The idea is to generate and discover forced choices and conflicts as early as possible.  In fact this is so important that it is worth a search at every step to try to discover and record forced choices and conflicts that are already visible.  It feels counterintuitive, but it really does make a difference.

But if you do all of this, the dynamic programming approach that was just fine for 5 boxes will become faster, but you'll still only be able to handle slightly larger problems than a naive solution.  So go look at the research for better ideas than this dynamic programming approach.

(Incidentally the inclusion-exclusion approach has a term for every subset, so it also will blow up exponentially.)